# Detect pinch zoom in Windows phone (7.1)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, gesture-recognition

According to Silverlight toolkit the Gesture listener is to be considered deprecated

> The Gesture Listener should be considered deprecated for all Windows Phone 7.1 SDK development.

And no other suggestions are available.  In the absence of gesture listener what is the best way to detect pinch/zoom gestures in WP7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933.aspx). It is using the [ManipulationDelta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationdelta.aspx) class to handle touch and resizing.