# How can i zoom into a page for windows phone using c# or xml?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone

Hey i'm developing an app where i have to zoom into the page or a part of the page because the text is of small font.. a zooming facility like the one for the web browser would be perfect..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would look more around the web first where you might find things like this type of question being [asked on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870755/detect-pinch-zoom-in-windows-phone-7-1). Or look at [what others have done](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335069/Nice-panning-and-zooming-in-Windows-Phone-7), by [different methods](http://www.frenk.com/2011/03/windows-phone-7-correct-pinch-zoom-in-silverlight/). It's a good question, but one likely asked before. Hope this helps :)